# How to generate multidimensional data with specific clustering properties?

Tags: dataset, elki

In section 5.A of a research paper the researcher used the following synthetic datasets:

1. GAUSS consisted of six Gaussian clusters with identity
   covariance, each with 500 points in five dimensions. Their
   means were randomly assigned a value from zero to 10 in
   each dimension. Cluster means were required to be at least
   four Euclidean distance apart, and points were required to
   within two Euclidean distance of their cluster mean.
2. PAIRED consisted of three pairs of Gaussian clusters with
   identity covariance, each with 500 points in five dimensions.
   Each pair of Gaussians was placed around a mean with
   a randomly assigned value in each dimension from zero
   to 20 such that the Euclidean distance between paired
   Gaussian clusters was between four and eight, and the
   Euclidean distance between non-paired Gaussians was at
   least 12. Additionally, points were required to be within two
   Euclidean distance of their cluster mean.
3. ELONG consisted of five Gaussian clusters with identity
   covariance, each with 300 points in five dimensions. Their
   means were randomly assigned a value from zero to 50 in
   each dimension. To create elongated clusters in different
   dimensions, we multiplied the values of a single, distinct
   dimension for each cluster by 15. Cluster means were
   required to be at least five Euclidean distance apart.
4. UNIFORM consisted of eight clusters, each with 300
   points in three dimensions. Each cluster had its points
   uniformly distributed in a 3x3x3 box around a randomly
   assigned center in a 10x10x10 cube. Cluster centers were
   required to be five Euclidean distance apart.
5. RINGS consisted of 2 ring clusters centered around (0,0),
   a larger outer ring with radius 2 and a smaller inner ring of
   radius 1. 400 points were evenly spaced by degrees on the
   inner ring.

---

http://postimg.org/image/jo4rjztjz/

---

I don't have these datasets. I tried to contact the researcher but of no use.

How to create these datasets? Is there any kind of tool to create them?

[Original Paper can be found here](https://bitbucket.org/parashararamsees/clustering-quality-measure/downloads)

Comment: Please post the xml you are sing. it should have 6 clusters, obviously.

Comment: If you have a new question, feel free to delete the question and ask anew. But don't **replace** one question with another, that is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation and examples on the ELKI data set generator can be found here:
http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/wiki/DataSetGenerator

The generator in ELKI currently cannot produce *ring-shaped* clusters (only *spherical*), and also does not support clipping points at a certain maximum distance.
It generates independent samples for each dimension *independently*. The only supported operation that uses more than one dimension at a time is the rotation operation. Generating ring-shaped clusters, or clipping clusters based on distance from a mean means a form of *dependence* of values that is currently not supported.

You will need to either contact the authors of that publication, or
**write a program to generate such data** yourself. It's not that hard; but it may not be worth the effort to generate such synthetic data - it's not a realistic scenario in my opinion.